# Specifying the Title of a new Google Sheet using a URL Parameter (https://sheet.new?title=XXXXXXX)

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs-api, google-workspace

Is there any way to specify the title of a new Google Sheet document, using ONLY URL parameters?

Example:

- The following URL will open a new, blank Google Doc. Where "**XXX**"
  is, you can specify what you want the title of your new document to
  be:

  - https://docs.google.com/document/create?title=**XXX**
- The same goes for creating a new Google Slides document:

  - https://docs.google.com/presentation/create?title="**XXX**"
- However, if you apply the same pattern to a new Google Sheet, such as:

  - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create?title="**XXX**"
  - This link WILL open a new Google Spreadsheet, but the title is blank.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems this option is not working like the examples that you have provided.

A workaround that you could use is using the REST sheets API. Take a look at [`create`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/create) method.

You could integrate this HTTP request in a lot of environment to simulate your behavior.

---

Alternatively you could report this behavior inside google Sheets itself. This seems like a reasonable request you could make.

[image: Send feedback]

Comment: Hi Raserhin, thanks for the tip. Unfortunately the REST API will not work for the very specific scenario I'm to solve. I'm going to take your advice and use the feedback option. Thanks!!